# Function WorldToScreenPoint() not working as expected

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need little help with function WorldToScreenPoint(position), Could somebody guide me little bit ? I am using this function to display name of the city:

```
public class LabelsTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private Text nameLabel;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 cameraPos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
        nameLabel.transform.position = cameraPos;
    }
}
```

But problem is that I see UI with text two times, one above the plane which is perfect:

[image: In the scene]

but when I face away from the plane, I can see the label there, too.:

[image: on the other side of me from the plane]

I don't know if I am doing something wrong or it just not working as it should.

Thanks for help.

Comment: No, I think its different problem, mine text is on correct position but one more is on the opposite side.

Comment: Did you in general consider to use a `WorldSpace` canvas for that?

Comment: oh that's what going on. "a second one behind me" was pretty unclear.  Do `nameLabel.SetActive(cameraPos.z>0);`

Comment: @derHugo It seems like the question is really about culling the text when the object it is over is behind the camera. Not a duplicate

Comment: probably I need to somehow record a video for better understanding

Comment: @Branislav what happened when you took the code in the question and added `nameLabel.SetActive(cameraPos.z>0);` at the end of `Update`?

Comment: Yes, as @Ruzihm said, exactly

Comment: @Ruzihm Visual Studio underlined it and says: 'Text' doesn't contain a definition for 'SetActive'...

Comment: @Branislav My mistake, try `nameLabel.enabled = cameraPos.z>0;` instead.

Comment: Oh now I see .. you mean `WorldToScreenPoint` simply returns a position on the Screen even though it is behind the camera ... That's why I would use a `WorldSpace` canvas rather..

Comment: It's working! Thank you guys very much :)

Comment: @Branislav Now that the duplicate has been removed, I've added my answer below. [Be sure to upvote it or accept it if it helps you.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent the `Text` from rendering while it is behind the camera. Luckily, `WorldToScreenPoint` gives you a z component that tells you how far in front of the camera the point is. So, just set the `Text` to be enabled when `z>0` and disabled when `z<=0`:

```
public class LabelsTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private Text nameLabel;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 cameraPos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
        nameLabel.transform.position = cameraPos; 
        nameLabel.enabled = cameraPos.z>0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

That's because your 'Plane' is culling the backface, meaning when the Plane is up at a certain point higher than the Camera's Y position it goes invisible.
Here's a GIF of the problem.
https://gyazo.com/d22c51951d1e8abd07a354af7f48ffef

Comment: he can also just disable backface culling on the plane.

Comment: problem is that I am not going under plane, but another text is behind.

Comment: The question was worded poorly - second image is taken from when the camera is facing away from the plane.

Comment: While this is certainly true (answer is not necessarily *wrong*) Ruzihm is correct: the asker is moving the plane *behind the camera* which has a slightly different solution.

Comment: I would give him up-vote for trying to help me but i don't have enough reputation yet :D